# I try to insert a blob file into MySQL database in Python, but keep getting mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000)

Tags: python, sql, syntax, blob

When trying to insert a blob file into a MySQL database, I get errors. This is sample of my code:

```
@pyqtSlot()
    def on_click(self):
        file_name = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open File', 'c:\\', 'Image Files (*.png *.jpg *gif)')
        image_path = file_name[0]

        self.converttobinary(image_path)

    def converttobinary(self, filename):
        with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
            binarydata = file.read()

        mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO imagestore (imgg) VALUES(%s)" % (binarydata))

        mydb.commit()
        print("image file inserted succesfully")
```

However, when I run the code I keep getting:

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x00\xd9\x00\x00\x01\x11\x08\x06\x00' at line 1

Answer (score 1):

quote the value for the column :

```
mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO imagestore (imgg) VALUES('%s')" % (binarydata))
```